# Django + 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte + cython

Tags: python, c, django, character-encoding, cython

I am running a django app on ubuntu 11.04, and am using cython to call a third party api written in C. When i compile everything for the api which is written C, and run a python script outside of django to test the api, i get all the calls working correctly.

I call the api and it returns 3 parameters as strings:

'36',
'029',
'973345'

However, when i tried to call the api from within django and display on the front end i get the error :

```
Type Error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Below is an example of what is inside of my cython file to make the api call to the c api(ccapi):

```
 cimport ccapi
 def get_params(self):
   cdef char municipalityCode_pt[128]
   cdef char schoolCode_pt[128]
   cdef char transitDistrictCode_pt[128]

   return ccapi.get_params(municipalityCode_pt, schoolCode_pt,transitDistrictCode_pt)
```

The example i run from the example python script which works is pretty straightforward:

```
import ccapilib
print ccapilib.ccapilib()
```

This prints the three params that i passed in with their values set correctly ('36',
'029',
'973345').

When i try the same thing within my django app, it causes the following error:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

whether i try to print the call to the api in python, or if i call it from the front end to be displayed in the template this error occurs.

If there is any other info you need i will have no problem supplying.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the exact line where the exception raises and the surrounding code?

Comment: Guess django always assumes strings to be utf8 encoded. You will need to check what encoding is used in the Cython output string. And then maybe decode it first! Or can you try codecs.encode(theValueToBeReturned, 'utf-8') inside the cython module, just before returning?

Comment: Not sure if it should be 'utf-8' or 'utf8'

Comment: def process_view(request):print ccapilib.ccapilib()...   this breaks when i call it from within the django view process_view.

Comment: What exactly is the signature of `ccapilib()`? What does it return?

Comment: it is a c method that takes in 3 parameters, all of type char *, sets them so i can access them after i call the method with their values set.

Comment: I don't follow.  You called it with (), so it takes no parameters.  More importantly, what does it _return_?  That's what you're printing, and what is the problem-string.

Comment: your right. it does not take parameters, it just returns them. there is call before it that sets everything up so that when i call this method with no params, it returns the computed values set from the call before(which you do not see). i am printing the 3 params that it returns. follow? or should i add a better description below.